# Plesk refuses to let me set a new SSL certificate

Tags: https, godaddy, plesk

I got a problem when I try to update/change a SSL certificate on a PLESK managed server. One problem might be that I am not so confident at this topic.

The setup is the following: 
I use an virtual server, which I have access to via PLESK. Two websites are running on the server, and are reachable via two domains. One of the domains is secured with a SSL certificate which will end soon. 
I bought a certificate renewal on godaddy.com followed this instruction: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5354/ssl-certificate-renewal-parallels-plesk-panel

The problem is in step 12 of the instruction

> 12.) At the top of the page, change the SSL Certificate drop-down menu to the certificate you have just installed.

There is no drop-down menu which i could pick from.

Plesk says: "Certificate XYZ installed (owned by another user)" where the drop-down should be.

I double checked my user accounts - there is only one administrator (which i used).

Has anyone an idea? 
Do I have to change something on web server level?

Comment: Have you tried looking at different instruction set, eg these look more accurate to me > https://support.hostgator.com/articles/how-can-i-install-an-ssl-certificate-plesk-10

Comment: @user29671 Maybe you can add the above to an answer with a quick summary of the link and Mathias can accept it so that the question can be considered closed?

Comment: I tried to write an answer but was not allowed to, yet.

Comment: @Mathias I see, thanks for letting me know - maybe by tomorrow it will.

Answer (score 1):

The guide (https://support.hostgator.com/articles/how-can-i-install-an-ssl-certificate-plesk-10) recommended by user29671 worked:

1. Login to your Parallels Plesk Panel
2. In the left hand menu, click on Tools & Settings
3. Click the SSL Certificates link
4. Click the Add SSL Certificate icon
5. Enter a certificate name and the settings for your Certificate Signing Request (CSR)
6. Click the Request button to generate the Private Key which your SSL issuer will need, or click Self-Signed to issue your own certificate.
7. Once you have the certificate codes, you can upload them in the "Upload certificate files" section and click the Send File button, or you can paste the codes in the "Upload certificate as text" section and click the Send Text button
8. Go back to Tools & Settings
9. Click the IP Addresses link
10. Click the IP related to your domain
11. For the "SSL certificate" drop down, select the name of your SSL certificate
12. Click the OK button
13. Go back to Tools & Settings
14. Under Server Management, click the Services Management link
15. Restart the Web Server (Apache) service

To use the highest PLESK account you have access to did the trick. 
In my case I had one PLESK account for the whole virtual server and one for each domain. I could change the SSL certificate on server level when the other accounts just displayed "owned by another user".

thanks to /u/user29671 for pointing me on the guide.